# Change mediatype of Spring errors

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am running a simple spring-boot web application api. The problem is when I throw an exception, or spring throws an exception, the exception is always thrown in Http, springs default error page. 
Is there a way to get the errors to default to another mediatype, say, JSON? 
Basically I **always** want json, even on errors.
I do not want to have to write a custom @ExceptionHandler for each exception type as that is just plain terrible..

Update: Here is what I am currently trying:

```
@ControllerAdvice
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class ErrorWritter extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

  @Override
  public ResponseEntity<Object> handleExceptionInternal(Exception ex, Object body, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
    String response = "{\"status\":\""
        + status.toString()
        + "\",\"generic message\":\""
        + status.getReasonPhrase()
        + "\",\"specific message\":\""
        + ex.getMessage()
        + "\" }";

    return new ResponseEntity<Object>(response, headers, status);
  }
}
```

This doesn't seem to do anything however. Is there something I need to do in order to get spring to recognize that I want it to use this?

Please note: I am using Java config and NOT xml config.

Answer (score 0):

There is pretty good info in the following article:
http://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc

you can create a model for your error such as:

```
public class ErrorInfo {
    public final String url;
    public final String ex;

    public ErrorInfo(String url, Exception ex) {
        this.url = url;
        this.ex = ex.getLocalizedMessage();
    }
}
```

And an error handler that uses that returns a representation of that model:

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
@ExceptionHandler(MyBadDataException.class)
@ResponseBody ErrorInfo handleBadRequest(HttpServletRequest req, Exception ex) {
    return new ErrorInfo(req.getRequestURL(), ex);
}
```

If you want more details on how the @ExceptionHandler works in spring, look at the spring docs:
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-exceptionhandlers

Comment: how do I get it to also handle the errors that Spring itself throws?

Comment: In the same article you will find references to `@ControllerAdvice`. That's the nicest way to use `@ExceptionHandler` globally.

Comment: @pragmatical @DaveSyer Ok, the article says all I have to do is extend the `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` but its not very specific on how to do it correctly. I edited my question above with what I have so far.

Comment: What about a simple `@ControllerAdvice` with a single `@ExceptionHandler` for all exceptions? Populate whatever state you need there in request attributes and then forward to a normal MVC `@Controller` where you can render JSON or an HTML view or whatever you like using normal content negotiation.

Comment: P.S. Spring Boot does that for you pretty much (in 1.1 almost literally, in 1.0 if you use the Actuator something similar happens).

Comment: @DaveSyer the problem with that is that it does not handle Spring exceptions. It only handles the exceptions I throw.

Comment: Yeah, a couple of ways of getting it to work, but my preference is to use the `@ControllerAdvice` annotation on a the class that has the exception handler as @Dave Syer suggests, than just ensure you have the <mvc:annotation-driven/>  configuration in your spring-servlet.xml file, there is a nice tutorial here: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-exception-handling-controlleradvice-annotation/  Hope that helps

Comment: @Humdinger in Boot we use a global error page in the servlet container that points to the same /error handler, so you should get the same error page (or JSON depending on content negotiation) for all exceptions.